# localhost/phpmyadmin is not opening in opera browser

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp, opera

for several hours I was trying to open `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/` in `Opera browser` but get nothing more than a blank screen with no errors in console, after that I opened it in `Internet Explorer` and page opened smoothly.

Note: using `XAMPP`

What can be the reason?

Answer (score 3):

You can acces with the IP http://127.0.0.1 or in a privacy mode. If you want force the name, try modify the route file in C://Windows/System32/drivers/etc/host